# Transferring mirrored UV map

Tags: uv

I have two objects [A] and [B].

[A] is a simple geometric form and [B] is same as [A] but mirored.

Both Meshes are made in Sketchup.

What I want is to create UV map for [A] and then transfer it to [B]. However the result is that the uv map for [B] is messed up.

What is interesting is that if in Blender I delete [B] then copy [A] and mirror it then I can transfer the UV map without a problem.

That might be a somewhat of a solution but I would like to see if anyone knows some decent way of transferring UV`s in this situation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I will leave the answer here if anyone else has the same problem in the future.

1.Select the model you want the UVs copied to, then the model you will copy them from.

2.Press Control+Shift+T to transfer mesh data.

3.Select Vertex Group and click the Auto transform checkbox.

4.Press Control+Shift+T and choose UVs